# PHP batch emails

Tags: php

Suppose my web host has an email limit per script.  Is there some way to batch my emails and get the script to restart itself upon exit?

Comment: If your web host has an email limit per script, the hosting service might consider circumventing it a violation of their TOS. I'd drop them an eMail and ask if you may do that what you are attempting. Also note that your host might be considered a spam host if your bulk mail is too much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+send+bulk+mail+php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Use BCC within e-mails
2. Create a for-loop an loop through the dataset, each time: mail a bucket of mails which are allowd to be send at once

Comment: Using BCC makes emails look impersonal. The solution would be to put emails in a queue and send them of in batches.

Comment: That´s true, so point 2 would be a solution, or your cron idea...

Answer (score 0):

### Sending Email Via Google App Engine

In my opinion the best idea is just to learn the basic of python and [send your email](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html) using google app engine. Google App Engine allows you to send 1000 emails a day without charge and after that they have a real generous fee($0.0001 per recipient) if you ask me.

To sent email you only need this code(genius if you ask me):

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

mail.send_mail(sender="Example.com Support <support@example.com>",
              to="Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>",
              subject="Your account has been approved",
              body="""
Dear Albert:

Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
access new features.

Please let us know if you have any questions.

The example.com Team
""")
```

if you hook it up to a [controller(webapp)](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/overview.html) you could sent emails for free(probably). I would advise you to watch this video: "[Developing and deploying an application on Google App Engine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfgO-LXGpTM)". It will only take you 10 minutes and will have learned to develop and deploy the code to Google App Engine. I would like to reiterate that it all can be done within 10 minutes :).

### Cron Job

Like others have mentioned you could setup a cron(job) if your webhosting(shared?) does allow this or use one of the freely available webcrons which provide you a webhook which gets called. Some examples by quick googling are:

- Again off course Google App Engine's [cron](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) with almost no restrictions.
- http://www.setcronjob.com/ => Free Account: You can create unlimited cron jobs every hour for FREE.
- http://www.mywebcron.com/ => Could not find quota
- http://www.cronwatch.com/ => CronWatch.com offers free online cronjobs for up to 10 cronjobs
- http://www.cronjobs.org/ => up to every 5 min
- http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/ => gets 5 free cron jobs.

And yet some list providing online Cron:

- http://blog.setcronjob.com/2009/06/list-of-free-cron-jobs.html
- http://www.onlinecronservices.com/

As you can see there are more then enough alternatives to batch up your emails and sent them out via cronjob.